# How do I get the tasks running as part of an ECS service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I would like to read the tasks running on a service through aws-sdk nodejs. I tried `describeServices` API but there is no information about the tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tasks are running on a cluster and managed by a service. You need to use the ListTasks API to get more information about the tasks in a cluster that belong to a certain service.

The API call should look something like this:

```js
var params = {
  cluster: '<cluster-name>',
  serviceName: '<service-name>'
};
ecs.listTasks(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

- [API Docs for the Javascript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ECS.html#listTasks-property)